# Create a SQL Server Express instance of MSSQLLocalDB on a client computer

Tags: c#, windows, sql-server-express

I am facing an issue since 2 week so here I am requesting your help.

I'm developing a tool in C# (Visual Studio 2017, SQL Server Express, WPF window)
this tool has to fill a word template automatically, and there are no problem with it. Thing is, since the tool needs to work with a local database (SQL Server Express), I have to make it create an instance of `MSSQLLocalDB` on each client who needs to use the tool.

When I launch it in debug mode on my own computer it works perfectly, but when I try to deploy it on a client computer, I get an error:

> Access denied for user 'username'

I added the `.mdf` database in the resource folder, I changed the `BuildAction` to `Content` and create the following snippet :

```
string DBpath = Path.GetTempPath() + "LocalDatabaseCopy.mdf"; 

if(!File.Exists(DatabasePath))
{
    File.WriteAllBytes(DBpath, Propreties.Resources.LocalDatabse);
}
```

By doing this, I check if a copy of my local database exists on the client computer, if not it copies the local database to the temp folder of the client computer.

I manually checked if the copy exists in the temp folder and it does, but the tool won't use it, so in the connection string I set the datasource to `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` and added the following line

```
builder.AttachDatabase = LocalDatabaseCopy.mdf
```

Now it uses the local copy but I get an error telling me that there are no instance of `MSSQLLocalDB` on the client computer, even when I pack it up in a setup with `SqlServerLocalDB` as a requirement. I really need to make it work on any client can someone explain me how to create a local instance of `MSSQLLocalDB` on each client computer and telling the tool to use it?

Comment: You need a database engine, the mdf file is not enough. You might consider [using a server-less database like Sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite) which would be much easier to manage.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, any suggestion ? How should i do ? do i have to drop all my database to recreates it or i can directly use the .mdf file ?

Comment: Take a look on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You [might be able to import your existing database](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/Migrate-a-SQL-Server-database-to-SQL-Server-Compact-or-SQLite) - I've never tried this myself. Your code will have to change too - where you have "Sql" you would use "Sqlite", e.g.: `SqlConnection` becomes `SqliteConnection`

Comment: Ok, so I come back here because I have another issue.

So I have switch to Sqlite but I would like to k ow if there a way to visualize database structure (like sql server, right click on database new query and select statement, table appears as a schema), is it possible to do so with sqlite?

I would like to specify that since the tool is for my business, I can't download from web but I can with nugget packages.

And second thing, what should I specify on connection string to query on sqlite db? I just need to change datasource to local db path or is there anything else to change?

Thanks